# Spring State Machine wont change state

Tags: spring-statemachine

I'm trying to put together a very simple Spring State Machine, but it doesn't seem to want to change state:
(It's important to note that even though I am using Spring State Machine, and the rest of the application is a Spring app, I cannot use the annotation driven approach to define the machine. I have to use the builders)

```
    StateMachineBuilder.Builder<String, String> builder = StateMachineBuilder.builder();

    try {
        builder.configureConfiguration()
                .withConfiguration()
                .beanFactory(new StaticListableBeanFactory())
                .listener(new StateMachineListenerAdapter<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(State<String, String> from, State<String, String> to) {
                        System.out.println("State change to " + to.getId());
                    }
                });

        builder.configureStates()
                .withStates()
                .initial("initialState")
                .states(Stream.of("initialState", "state1", "state2", "state3").collect(Collectors.toSet()))
                .end("state3");

        builder.configureTransitions()
                .withExternal()
                .state("initialState")
                .target("state1")
                .event("event1")
                .action(stateContext ->
                    System.out.println(String.format("Event %s triggered", stateContext.getEvent()))
                );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    StateMachine<String, String> stateMachine = builder.build();

    stateMachine.start();

    boolean complete = stateMachine.isComplete();
    System.out.println("Statemachine is complete: " + complete);

    State<String, String> state = stateMachine.getState();
    System.out.println(state.getId());

    stateMachine.sendEvent("event1");

    state = stateMachine.getState();
    System.out.println(state.getId());
```

When I run the above, I am expecting that the first state is `initialState`, and that when I send the event `event1` the state will be changed to `state1`. I get the following output:

```
State change to initialState
Statemachine is complete: false
initialState
initialState
```

This tells me the listener triggers once when the machine first starts and sets the initial state, that for some reason the state machine reports it is incomplete, that the state is `initialState` before I send the event, and that the state is still `initialState` after I send the event.
There are no errors either on starting of the state machine, or when I send the event, and the action in the transition is never run.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - I was configuring the transition incorrectly!
This is how it should be:

```
    builder.configureTransitions()
            .withExternal()
            .source("initialState")
            .target("state1")
            .event("event1")
            .action(stateContext ->
                System.out.println(String.format("Event %s triggered", stateContext.getEvent()))
            );
```

IE. I was originally calling `.state`, which it should have been `.source`